# How to add user object controler in my visualforce custom page in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I want to add user object from my custom page is it possible in salesforce ?

Comment: I think you need to clarify whether you're trying add a user, or trying to use the User standard controller — your title and question seem to suggest two different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user as the standard controller.

I am not too sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey PepeFloyd, we've got an Area 51 proposal running for a Salesforce specific Stack Exchange site, care to sign up? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce?referrer=4-k5FqV679TWbBGLxdLUKg2

Comment: Saw your message just now. Signing up!